# NG-Repeat doesn't update cleanly when scope is updated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I have a list of workspaces:

```
<li class="workspace-object" ng-repeat="w in workspaces | filter:searchQuery" ng-click="selectWorkspace(w)">
    <a href="" class="workspace-link">{{w.name | titleCase }}</a>
</li>
```

That List gets updated in the database by some function, and then I call the loadWorkspaces function below, to re-populate the $scope.workspaces object

```
$scope.loadWorkspaces = function() {
  APIService.getWorkspaces().then(function(data){
    $scope.workspaces = data;
  });
}
```

When this happens, the $scope.workspaces, when logged out, reads the right updated information immediately, however, the ng-repeat DUPLICATES, before it updates to the proper list. I have no idea why this happens. Any ideas?
In this example, I am updating the workspace title, and that update runs the loadworkspaces function.

[image: issue]

Comment: try `w in workspaces track by $index`

Comment: Oh my god. I really am that much of a dumb dumb sometimes. Thanks dcodesmith! Set that as an answer and I'll mark it for you to get some points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this ...

```
w in workspaces track by $index
```

> When the contents of the collection change, ngRepeat makes the corresponding > changes to the DOM:
>
> - When an item is added, a new instance of the template is added to the DOM.
> - When an item is removed, its template instance is removed from the DOM.
> - When items are reordered, their respective templates are reordered in the DOM.
>
> By default, ngRepeat does not allow duplicate items in arrays. This is because when there are duplicates, it is not possible to maintain a one-to-one mapping between collection items and DOM elements.
>
> If you do need to repeat duplicate items, you can substitute the default tracking behavior with your own using the track by expression.
>
> For example, you may track items by the index of each item in the collection, using the special scope property $index

Comment: Thanks bud! Hopefully this SO will help someone who really needs the help and not a pro like me who clearly hasn't had enough coffee in the last 2 days this has been giving me a problem. Lol!

Comment: These things happen, glad I could be of help ;)

Comment: Life saver! Had exactly the same scenario where I'd ajax down a new dataset and then blast over an array bound to an ng-repeat which would then double up the results in the ui for a split second before showing me the correct, new, result set.  I did have a track by that was tracking by the id, but changing it to index totally fixed the issue, presumably because I'm now forcing Angular to reuse the li's from before rather than create new ones.

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer did not help me (Using Angular 1.1.10), my repeat was still updating delayed. I struggled for ages before I got it working.

Instead of repeating my custom directive like so;

```
<my-directive ng-repeat="item in myarray track by item.id" some-binding="item"></my-directive>
```

I (magically) got it working after moving the ng-repeat to a (non-directive) parent element, like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in myarray track by item.id">
    <my-directive some-binding="item"></my-directive>
</div>
```

Comment: THANK YOU! This is exactly what worked. I'm assuming there was some kind of issue with conflicting priorities on the directives and components for whatever reason, but after implementing your solution, it worked like a charm! This is especially good for me considering the animations, scrolling I have on this thing... (It's a pipeline diagram with a scroll that can be 10,000 or more pixels wide)